# When seeding questions, should you ask questions you already know the answer to?

Tags: discussion

Because I've been doing a lot of that.

Answer (score 4):

[Robert Cartaino answered a similar question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-generic-is-too-generic/27#27):

> Remember, this is the REAL site. We're
>   not asking "seed" or "sample"
>   questions here. There are enough
>   people on this site (and a lot more
>   coming) that we don't need seeders,
>   per se. It would be very bad for this
>   site if it was loading up with
>   questions, just for the sake of asking
>   questions. There are real people
>   putting real effort into answering
>   your questions.
>
> Please use this site is to ask real
>   questions about problems you actually
>   have.
>
> In terms of how to ask, if you have a
>   specific question, ask a specific
>   question. If you think your question
>   applies to a more general case,
>   include that information, too. Any
>   additional information you provide in
>   your question is helpful.

Comment: agree, but as Andreas said, you can ask about real problems you *had* in the past.

Comment: I think at this point it is counter-productive to answer your own question immediately. Let someone else try. The thing that made me engage with the StackOverflow community the most was the first time I answered a question.

Answer (score 3):

I was under the impression that was fine, I'd recommend leaving it a while before answering though just for the look of it.

Comment: yeah, that's what i've been doing too.

Answer (score 2):

I personally asked real problems I **had** but that I now resolved.

So I know the answers to my own questions, but they are real problems I had, they are not questions I made up just to fill the website.